# $sql="SELECT * FROM glasanje where ime=''

Tags: mysql, insert

I need help . Here's the code . I want to vote from the table to pull out all the names , and to introduce them across the chart .

I tried to use * but it does not work :)

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM glasanje where ime='*'
```

Comment: If you want all records, don't attempt to use a wildcard like `ime='*'`. Instead just omit the `WHERE` clause entirely. `SELECT * FROM glasanje`

Comment: try `"SELECT * FROM glasanje where ime <> ''` to select all non-empty names

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  The description doesn't explain what you want to do with the query -- SQL, for instance, doesn't support anything called a "chart".

Comment: ` $sql="SELECT * FROM glasanje where ime='*' ORDER BY brglasova ASC ";
if (!$q=$mysqli->query($sql)) 

I need to get datas from mysql table, and to intorduce in chart.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to extract only the names (ime), you have to put it in the `SELECT` statement, try this way:

```
SELECT ime
  FROM glasanje
```

`SELECT *` means that you want to see all the columns, `SELECT ime` just the column ime.

The `WHERE` clause is used to select a subset of rows, for example if you want just the people with name Filip, you can write `WHERE ime ='Filip'`

Anyway these are a basic SQL functionality, I think you should try to study it a bit.

Comment: I understand, but i need all people from table ime. See my code

header("Content-type: application/json");?>{"glasanje":<?php
require_once "konekcija.php";
$sql="SELECT * FROM glasanje where ime= ORDER BY brglasova ASC ";
if (!$q=$mysqli->query($sql)){

Comment: from your code the table name seems to be "glasanje", if you need all rows just remove the `where ime= `. If you need all columns `SELECT *` is fine